# linking object literal to HTML address

Tags: javascript, html

Okay here is my problem statement: I am trying to create an object with these properties `{"name":"John Doe","email":"name@domain.com"}` and I'm trying to print out an HTML link to that email address by accessing the object's properties.

Here is my object so far:

```js
var firstObject = {
  name: 'John Doe' ,
  email: 'name@domain.com'
};
console.log(firstObject);
```

I want my console.log output to be something that prints out the href link by accessing the object something like this:

```
"<a href="mailto:name@domain.com">John Doe</a>"
```

Comment: I think what you are asking is how to make an `<a>` element where the `href` is the email from your object and the content is the name from your object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build the element in javascript and then log it, I would do this:

```
var element = '<a href="mailto:' + firstObject["email"] + '">' + firstObject["name"] + '</a>'
console.log(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
console.log("mailto:" + firstObject.email);
```

And if you want it in a link:

```
<a href=""></a>

<script>
    document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].setAttribute("href", "mailto:" + firstObject.email;
    document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innrHTML = firstObject.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried this code and works fine.

i used DOMContenLoaded

The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- link to external JS file.  Note that <script> has an
  end </script> tag -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Task 6 </title>
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  var firstObject = {
  name: 'John Doe' ,
  email: 'name@domain.com'
};
      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].setAttribute("href", "mailto:" + firstObject.email);
      document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML =firstObject.name;
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href=""></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are welcome.Here some link where you can read documentation and to do an exercises:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/
and
JavaScript Guide - MDN - Mozilla